# What is a better way to write this Javascript hover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works but of course is a bit redundant. Items can also be dynamically added so I need to have it always increment by one. What is a better way to write this into one function?

Update: Just added the markup. Bascially when a user hovers any of the list item a classname should be attached to the banner div. e.g., banner_0, banner_1, etc.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#" data="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="">item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="">item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="">item6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="">item7</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="banner" class=""></div>


$('#list a').eq(0).hover(
function() {
    $('#banner').addClass('banner_0');
}, 
function() {
    $('#banner').removeClass();
}
);

$('#list a').eq(1).hover(
function() {
    $('#banner').addClass('banner_1');
}, 
function() {
    $('#banner').removeClass();
}
);

$('#list a').eq(2).hover(
function() {
    $('#banner').addClass('banner_2');
}, 
function() {
    $('#banner').removeClass();
}
);

$('#list a').eq(3).hover(
function() {
    $('#banner').addClass('banner_3');
}, 
function() {
    $('#banner').removeClass();
}
);
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.index` like below,

```
$('#list a').hover(
function() {
    $('#banner').addClass('banner_' + $(this).index());
}, 
function() {
    $('#banner').removeClass();
}
);
```

Comment: How do I apply this for when a user hovers over each list item? It only works for the first list item.

Comment: Are you duplicating ID? ID should be unique. Show us your markup, I think you are duplicating ID and so it worked only for first item.

Comment: Do you have other items inside the `li`, if not bind `.hover` to `li` and it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dLyTK/

Comment: Awesome. How would I start from 1 instead of 0? I tried index()+1 but that makes it two digits.

Comment: @ChoyChan Wrap it inside like `($(this).index() +1)`